# getting error while passing a array through loop

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

This my controller function

```
public function update_monthly() {
        $data = $this->student_model->get_due_info();

        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_id($value);
            $grade = $this->student_model->get_grade_by_id($value);
            $grade_due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_grade($grade);
            $new_due = $due + $grade_due;
            $this->db->set('md_due',$new_due, FALSE);
        }   
    }
```

I am getting following error

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Notice

    Message: Array to string conversion

    Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

    Line Number: 427
```

and

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT `md_due` FROM (`monthly_due`) WHERE `md_student_id` = Array

Filename: F:\xampp\htdocs\student\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

**Model Code**

```
public function get_due_by_id($id) {
        $this->db->select('md_due');
        $this->db->from('monthly_due');
        $this->db->where('md_student_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_due_by_grade($id) {
        $this->db->select('dt_fee');
        $this->db->from('due_table');
        $this->db->where('dt_grade', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_grade_by_id($id) {
        $this->db->select('grade');
        $this->db->from('student_info');
        $this->db->where('student_gen_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    public function get_due_info() {

        $this->db->select('md_student_id');
        $this->db->from('monthly_due');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Since CI Active Record returns associative array please change `$due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_id($value);` to $due = `$this->student_model->get_due_by_id($value[ARRAY_INDEX | COLUMN NAME]);`

Comment: Can you paste model code here?

Comment: It is because you need to pass id to your get_due_by_id model function.If you are returning array object then use
get_due_by_id($value['id_col_name'])

or if you are returning stdClass object then use
get_due_by_id($value->id_col_name)

Feel free to let me know if any doubts.

Comment: $due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_id($value['md_student_id']); is getting the same error

Comment: post your model code

Comment: @MRSrinivas Do you think the problem is with model code?

Comment: Pass `$value['md_student_id']` to the model instead of `$value` in controller.

Comment: try to print your `$data` first so you can see what is the result of your model function, if there is everything you need then try to call with the same index in your `$data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `$value['md_student_id']` to the model instead of `$value` in controller.

```
$data = $this->student_model->get_due_info();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_id($value['md_student_id'] );
    $grade = $this->student_model->get_grade_by_id($value['md_student_id']);
    $grade_due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_grade($grade[0]['grade']);
    //Add remaining logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing whole the array to your model not just the value you want

```
$due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_id($value);
```

the right thing is to pass

```
$value['md_student_id']
```

this is the value you actually want to pass

replace your code with this

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
            $due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_id($value['md_student_id'] );
            $grade = $this->student_model->get_grade_by_id($value['md_student_id']);
            $grade_due = $this->student_model->get_due_by_grade($grade[0]['grade']);
            $new_due = $due + $grade_due;
            $this->db->set('md_due',$new_due, FALSE);
        }
```

Comment: according to @mudasser Ali I tried this solution and it didn't work.

Comment: just echo $value[0]['md_student_id'] before you call your model to ensue that you id is not array

Comment: @HossamAldeenAhmed: Why do you think `$value[0]['md_student_id'] ` only ??

Comment: if you print the array which returned from the mode it will looks like array(0=>array(id=>'you_id'))

Comment: just print the $value and give me what really returned